# Android: Flurry Banner Ad is not displaying

Tags: android, flurry

I have integrated Flurry banner ad on my app. On logcat it says `BannerAdObject` created, but ad is not displayed. I've attached the code and logcat. I have not found any solution for this issue .

```
mBanner =(RelativeLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.banner);
         mFlurryAdBanner = new FlurryAdBanner(getActivity(), mBanner, mAdSpaceName);
        mFlurryAdBanner.setListener(bannerAdListener);


FlurryAdBannerListener bannerAdListener = new FlurryAdBannerListener() {

        @Override
        public void onFetched(FlurryAdBanner adBanner) {
            adBanner.displayAd();
        }

        //... other Overriden method goes here
    };
```

Logcat

```
05-02 07:16:47.770 15810-15810/com.test W/FlurryAgent: 'setLogEnabled' method is deprecated.
05-02 07:16:47.770 15810-15810/com.test W/FlurryAgent: 'setLogLevel' method is deprecated.
05-02 07:16:47.810 15810-15810/com.test W/FlurryAgent: 'init' method is deprecated.
05-02 07:16:48.100 15810-15964com.test I/FlurryAgent: New main file also not found. returning..
05-02 07:16:48.105 15810-15964/com.test I/FlurryAgent: New main file also not found. returning..
05-02 07:16:48.115 15810-15964/com.test I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.os.StatFs.getAvailableBlocksLong, referenced from method com.flurry.sdk.ja.a
05-02 07:16:48.120 15810-15964/com.test I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.webkit.WebSettings.getDefaultUserAgent, referenced from method com.flurry.sdk.dx$1.a
05-02 07:16:48.125 15810-15964/com.test W/FlurryAgent: Flurry session started for context:com.test.SplashActivity@4273f6d8
05-02 07:16:48.125 15810-15964/com.test W/FlurryAgent: Flurry session resumed for context:com.test.SplashActivity@4273f6d8
05-02 07:16:48.140 15810-15964/com.test I/dalvikvm: Failed resolving Lcom/flurry/sdk/bt; interface 2723 'Lcom/facebook/ads/AdListener;'
05-02 07:16:48.140 15810-15964/com.test W/dalvikvm: Link of class 'Lcom/flurry/sdk/bt;' failed
05-02 07:16:48.140 15810-15964/com.test E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'com.flurry.sdk.bt', referenced from method com.flurry.sdk.bu.a
05-02 07:16:48.140 15810-15964/com.test W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 3271 (Lcom/flurry/sdk/bt;) in Lcom/flurry/sdk/bu;
05-02 07:16:48.140 15810-15964/com.test I/dalvikvm: Failed resolving Lcom/flurry/sdk/bv; interface 2728 'Lcom/facebook/ads/InterstitialAdListener;'
05-02 07:16:48.140 15810-15964/com.test W/dalvikvm: Link of class 'Lcom/flurry/sdk/bv;' failed
05-02 07:16:48.140 15810-15964/com.test E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'com.flurry.sdk.bv', referenced from method com.flurry.sdk.bu.a
05-02 07:16:48.140 15810-15964/com.test W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 3273 (Lcom/flurry/sdk/bv;) in Lcom/flurry/sdk/bu;
05-02 07:16:48.140 15810-15964com.test I/dalvikvm: Failed resolving Lcom/flurry/sdk/bt; interface 2723 'Lcom/facebook/ads/AdListener;'
05-02 07:16:48.140 15810-15964/com.test W/dalvikvm: Link of class 'Lcom/flurry/sdk/bt;' failed
05-02 07:16:48.140 15810-15964/com.test D/dalvikvm: DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0x6634 at 0x0c in Lcom/flurry/sdk/bu;.a
05-02 07:16:48.145 15810-15964/com.test I/dalvikvm: Failed resolving Lcom/flurry/sdk/bv; interface 2728 'Lcom/facebook/ads/InterstitialAdListener;'
05-02 07:16:48.145 15810-15964/com.test W/dalvikvm: Link of class 'Lcom/flurry/sdk/bv;' failed
05-02 07:16:48.145 15810-15964/com.test D/dalvikvm: DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0x664a at 0x0a in Lcom/flurry/sdk/bu;.a
05-02 07:16:48.165 15810-15964/com.test W/webview_proxy: java.lang.Throwable: Warning: A WebView method was called on thread 'FlurryAgent'. All WebView methods must be called on the UI thread. Future versions of WebView may not support use on other threads.
                                                                                 at android.webkit.WebView.checkThread(WebView.java:1895)

05-02 07:40:05.855 12475-12626/com.test D/FlurryAgent: Referrer file contents: null
05-02 07:40:09.090 12475-12626/com.test W/FlurryAgent: Flurry session resumed for context:com.test.HomeActivity@426ec9d8
05-02 07:40:09.445 12475-12661/com.test W/FlurryAgent: Analytics report sent.
05-02 07:40:10.840 12475-12626/com.test W/FlurryAgent: Flurry session paused for context:com.test.SplashActivity@4277efe8
05-02 07:40:14.440 12475-12475/com.test D/FlurryAgent: BannerAdObject created: com.flurry.sdk.q@42bed4d8
```

Comment: Please help me.I am stuck. I have searched a lot but not found any solution

Comment: Now getting this error: Ad server responded but sent no ad units.

Comment: @Aman Bansal Could you please help me

Comment: You are not actually fetching the ad. After you set the listener, you should call `mFlurryAdBanner.fetchAd()`.